# Qual a diferença dos métodos "include" e "then" do Consign?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou usando a biblioteca Consign em um exercício de criação de um back-end em Node.js.

Parte do código se apresenta assim:

```
consign()
    .include('./config/passport.js')
    .then('./config/middlewares.js')
    .then('./api')
    .then('./config/routes.js')
    .into(app)
```

Entendo que o `.then` carrega o código JS dos respectivos arquivos. Mas e o `.include`? Qual a diferença entre eles?

Comment: Não estou familiarizado com essa biblioteca. Já tentou olhar na documentação?

Comment: Só olhar o [código fonte](https://github.com/jarradseers/consign/blob/develop/lib/consign.js). Você vai perceber que o `then` nada mais é do que chamar a útlima função executada _novamente_ só que com outro parêmetro. Apesar do nome, a função não parece trabalhar com _Promises_.

Comment: Aqui o código: `Consign.prototype.then = function(entity) {
  this[this._lastOperation].call(this, entity);
  return this;
};`

Comment: Então basicamente nesse código que postei, onde estou usando apenas o include, usar o .then e o .include é a mesma coisa??? Porque razão será que criaram esse .then então???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embora a biblioteca utilize uma função chamada `then`, não confunda com Promises.

O `then`, nesse contexto, executa a última função executada. Veja no [código-fonte](https://github.com/jarradseers/consign/blob/develop/lib/consign.js):

```
Consign.prototype.then = function(entity) {
  this[this._lastOperation].call(this, entity);
  return this;
};
```

No seu exemplo, você chama `include` primeiro e na sequência uma trilha de chamadas `then`. Nesse caso, você está, por trás dos panos, chamando `include`.

O `then` começa a fazer sentido quando você usa outras funções além do `include`. Veja esse exemplo:

```
consign()
    .include('./config/passport.js') // muda o _lastOperation para include
    .then('./config/middlewares.js') // chama o include
    .then('./api')                   // chama o include
    .then('./config/routes.js')      // chama o include
    .exclude('./config/test.js')     // muda o _lastOperation para exclude
    .then('./config/test.js')        // chama o exclude
    .then('./config/test2.js')       // chama o exclude
    .into(app)
```

No final das contas, é só um açúcar sintático.